# PHP: json_decode cannot read escaped character strings

Tags: php, json, escaping, character, backslash

i want to read a .json file using file_get_contents which returns a string.
Then i use json_decode to create an array/object of it. Everything works.

My problem is that sometimes the string in the json file includes regex expressions.
These can not be decoded! Therefore the following notice message:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'Data' of non-object in
```

After a quick google search i found out that i have to double escape them. I tried to change it in the json file - it works.

```
From:
      "Block Proxy URL": "somesite.ab123regex(\d\d\d).top/fyli.php",
To:
      "Block Proxy URL": "somesite.ab123regex(\\d\\d\\d).top/fyli.php",
```

But i receive that file generated by an appliance so i can't change it every time manually.

So consequently i tried to automate it:

```
$archer_json_data = file_get_contents($filename);
str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $archer_json_data);
$archer_json_array = json_decode($archer_json_data)->Data;
```

which does not work. I also tried addslashes instead of str_replace, it does not work. why? According to the replies of my quick google search it works for them.

For debugging purposes i echo'ed `archer_json_data` before str_replace and after.. they are exactly the same. Why does my str_replace not work?

Comment: Why is this appliance generating invalid json?

Comment: Because the applicance does not add needed escapes from user inputs. Oh, well, i dont know what to say other than its not my day. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You shouldn't try to "fix" those invalid serializations. Rather focus on "salvaging" the content. If it's not nested structures, a more or less simple `/"(\w+)":\s*"(.+?)"/` key-value regex may help.

Comment: As paul mentioned you are not using the value from str_replace, you need to assign the return value to a variable. eg. `$archer_json_data = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $archer_json_data);`

Comment: Microsoft's JavaScriptSerializer() escapes "\" with "\\". PHP's json_decode() breaks when attempting to decode it. It throws invalid JSON data error. So it is not just a faulty appliance.  I used Second2none's approach. Either MS or PHP is doing it wrong.